# Is upsizing MS-Access to MS-SQL-Server version independent?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, upsizing

I am planning to upsize an Access 2010 database to a SQL Server version 11 (these are the versions I use in the moment).

I am familiar with Access since version 1.0 and, to a lesser extent, with SQL-Server since a couple of years. But the last time I upsized an Access database to SQL Server was many years ago.

Now I am studying articles on the internet about the automatic and manual upsizing. But almost all of these articles relate to Access versions 2003 or 2007 and earlier SQL Server versions.

Now my question: Did anything significant change about the upsizing process over the last years and versions or is it basically still the same process? Did certain things change so much that a recommendation i.e. for Access 2007 is irrelevant or maybe even wrong for 2010?

One example is this article which “Applies To: Access 2007”:
Move Access data to a SQL Server database by using the Upsizing Wizard
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5D74C0DF-C8CD-4867-8D07-E6E759D72924

Or this article from year 2000:
ACCESS DATABASES ( DSN vs DSN-LESS)
http://www.powerasp.net/content/database/dsn_vs_dnsless.asp

I am willing to read and learn but obviously I don’t want to waste my time reading staff which is outdated and now maybe wrong.

How is your experience with upsizing a new version of Access compared to an older version? Did something significant change?

Comment: The DSN-vs-DSN-LESS-Article does not apply to the question at all. It deals with using an Access-Backend for ASP (Active Server Pages).

Answer (score 2):

The Version of Microsoft SQL Server is negligible regarding your Question.

There are two important changes in the history of Access regarding SQL-Server-Backends.

1.) With Access 2000 Microsoft introduced the new ADP (Access Data Project) file type that allows closer integration of MS-SQL-Server-Databases as Backend using ADO (ActiveX Data Objects). This was the recommend way to build Access applications with SQL-Backend for a couple of years. 
However, after the release of Access 2010 Microsoft decided that they are not going to support the ADP-File-Type anymore and they **removed all support for ADPs** in Access 2013!

2.) Up until Access 2003 the DAO-Library (Data Access Objects) included support for ODBC-Direct-Workspaces, which allowed you to call stored procedures and functions on SQL-Server via DAO. But with Access 2007 Microsoft **removed ODBC-Direct** and hinted towards the ADO and ADP-Features to implement such stuff in your application. – When they later (Access 2013) changed their recommendation to use DAO instead of ADO/ADP for SQL-Connectivity, they did not provide any useful replacement for ODBC-Direct.

---

The current recommendation (by Microsoft) is to use Access with the DAO-Library and linked tables via ODBC to connect your Access-Frontend-Application to SQL-Server. Pass-Through-Queries are recommended for anything that is beyond a linked table or linked view.

I personally advise to extend this approach by combining DAO/linked-tables with an ADO-Connection to SQL-Sever in VBA to call Stored Procedures and Functions on SQL-Server, instead of Pass-Through-Queries. This obviously creates a bit of a technology mix-up but it tremendously increases your possibilities to interact with business logic implemented in the SQL-Server-Database.

If you keep all that in mind, most of the advice regarding Access-SQL-Server-Upsizing is still valid, no matter how old it is.